# 'Until loop' analogue needed - in order to continue bot dialog - after some status 'marker' is updated

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-bot-service

'Until loop' analogue needed to continuously read status variable from helper function - and then (when the status variable is 'as we need it') - to resume bot conversation flow.

In my bot (botbuilder v.3.15) I did the following:

1. During one of my dialogues I needed to open external url in order
   to collect some information from the user through that url.
2. After that I posted collected data (with conversation ID and other info) from that url to my bot app.js
   file
3. After that I needed to resume my bot conversation
4. For that I created helper file - helper.js in which 'marker' variable is 'undefined' when the data from url is not yet collected, and 'marker' variable is some 'string' when the data is collected and we can continue our bot conversation

**helper.js**

```
    var marker;

    module.exports = {
      checkAddressStatus: function() {
        return marker;
      },
      saveAddressStatus: function(options) {
        marker = options.conversation.id;
      }
    }
```

5. I can successfully update variable 'marker' with my data, by calling saveAddressStatus function from app.js.
6. However, when I get back to writing my code which is related to bot conversation flow (**To the place in code after which I opened url** - in file address.js, and from where I plan to **continuously** check the 'marker' variable whether it is already updated - in order to fire 'next()' command and continue with session.endDialogWithResult -> and then -> to further bot conversation flows - **I cannot find the equivalent of 'until loop' in Node.js** to resume my session in bot dialog - by returning 'next()' and continuing with the bot flow.

**address.js**

```
...
lib.dialog('/', [
    function (session, args, next) {
    ...
    next();
    },
    function (session, results, next) {
    // Herocard with a link to external url

    // My stupid infinite loop code, I tried various options, with promises etc., but it's all not working as I expect it
      while (typeof helper.checkAddressStatus() == 'undefined') {
        console.log('Undefined marker in address.js while loop')
      }

      var markerAddress = helper.checkAddressStatus();
      console.log(markerAddress);
      next(); // THE MOST IMPORTANT PART OF THE CODE - IF markerAddress is not 'undefined' - make another step in dialog flow to end dialog with result
   function(session, results) {
    ...session.endDialogWithResult({markerAddress: markerAddress})
}
...
```

Any ideas how to make a very simple 'until loop' analoque in this context - work?

Answer (score 0):

Having your bot stop and wait for a response is considered bad practice. If all of your bot instances are stuck waiting for the user to fill out the external form, your app won't be able to process incoming requests. I would at least recommend adding a timeout if you decide to pursue that route.

Instead of triggering your helper class in the endpoint you created, you should send a proactive message to the user to continue the conversation. To do this, you will need to get the conversation reference from the session and encode it in the URL that you send to the user. You can get the conversation reference from the session - session.message.address - and at the very least you will need to encode the bot id, conversation id, and the serviceUrl in the URL. Then when you send the data collected from the user back to the bot, include the conversation reference details for the proactive message. Finally, when your bot receives the data, recreate the conversation reference and send the proactive message to the user.

Here is how your conversation reference should be structured:

```
const conversationReference = {
    bot: {id: req.body.botId },
    conversation: {id: req.body.conversationId},
    serviceUrl: req.body.serviceUrl
};
```

Here is an example of sending a proactive message:

```
function sendProactiveMessage(conversationReference ) {
   var msg = new builder.Message().address(conversationReference );
   msg.text('Hello, this is a notification');
   msg.textLocale('en-US');
   bot.send(msg);
}
```

For more information about sending proactive messages, checkout these  [samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/v3-sdk-samples/Node/core-proactiveMessages) and this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-proactive-messages?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) on proactive messages.

Hope this helps!